# Como fazer Breakpoints com Susy?

Tags: css3, layout-responsivo, media-queries

Estou tendo problemas para gerar os Breakpoints de um projeto para o Celular (320px).

Quando coloco o Breakpoints ele lê até em Desktops, mais ficar certo no Celular também.

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  /* MEUS ESTILOS ESTÃO AQUI DENTRO */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já foi resolvido, ele estava dando o error de carregar em Desktop por causa do min-width.

O que eu fiz para resolver:

No meu arquivo base.scss criei uma variável $mobile e lá inseri:

```
$mobile: 320px 12 568px;
```

Aonde o primeiro valor (320px) é meu min-width, 12 é a quantidade de colunas do SUSY e o último valor (568px) gera o meu max-width.